# QGIS Methods for Batch/multiple shortest path calculations

Tags: qgis, batch, qgis-modeler, shortest-path

Is there an established method for running multiple shortest path analysis based on multiple start and end points?

I have a model outputting coordinate data and a road network with varying road types. I need to be able to run multiple  shortest path calcs and have those routes plotted.

I am fairly new to qgis and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use GDAL GNM functionality (see. http://gdal.org/gnm_tut.html and http://gdal.org/gnm_arch.html).

But you need GDAL build with GNM support (by now it disabled by default). You can grab GDAL with GNM here: http://nextgis.com/borsch/

If you prefer GUI utility, there is a plugin for QGIS - QNetwork (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qnetwork/) which utilize GDAL GNM. But there are some limits in plugin now (you need at least to layers - lines connected points). Also you need QGIS build with GDAL GNM - get it here: http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. I am trying to use the QNetwork plugin. However i am unable to create or load a network and the Options in this plugin window remains grey'd out. Is this due to a lack of supported layers that may be required?

Comment: This is because your QGIS based on GDAL without GNM. Plugin check if GNM is available and if no GNM, all buttons and menus marked disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by batch use of Processing> NetworkAnalysis> ShortestPath(PointToLayer). This can be run in batch.
I found the easiest way is to prepare the batch was to use a JSON file. The core of JSON can be prepared using a spreadsheet. Then concatenate the requires fields, copy & dump into a JSON editor to tweek the top and tail into the correct format. 
What is key to this is organising, preparing the data and the use of directories or folders. It considerable reducing calculation time if you constrain the network and potential start and/or end points to reasonable possibilities. I sieved out the road network and end points to within a 20km circumference. I finished up process about 15,000 start/end combinations in under one second per pair. So just over 4 hrs processing (best done overnight).

Comment: I'm doing this, and this solves. but it is not as efficient as expected because each shortest path process must create a graph first. if it's the same graph, then you're making the same graph over and over again which is quite unnecessary.